# Can we create nested batch statement by using cassandra cql

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I have a situation in which I need to execute a pair of statement together in batch

```
BEGIN BATCH

BEGIN BATCH
insert into abc(key,value)values(2,200.00)
insert into def(key,value)values(2,200.00)
APPLY BATCH;


BEGIN BATCH
insert into abc(key,value)values(2,200.00)
insert into def(key,value)values(2,200.00)
APPLY BATCH;


BEGIN BATCH
insert into abc(key,value)values(2,200.00)
insert into def(key,value)values(2,200.00)
APPLY BATCH;

APPLY BATCH;
```

This is the kind of thing I required can we do that in cql?

Comment: Why can't you just do all 6 statements inside one batch? What would be the purpose of the nested batches?

Comment: I have read some where batch transaction are atomic. So each have to process a batch comprises of pair of inserts. Like T1(a,b) T2(a,b). here T is an operation which contain two insert a and b such that if a get failed b should not executed.So i was thinking if i could have nested batch statement then it could server the purpose

Comment: but if you are batching them like T3(T1(a,b), T2(c,d)), what would you expect to happen if a & b were successful but d failed. What I am getting at is that you either want T(a, b, c, d) or T1(a,b) T2(c,d). The T3 batch is going to serve no purpose.

Comment: I think you are right